# appfuse 3.5 hbm2ddl schema export fail

Tags: appfuse

I tried appfuse 3.5(basic+springMVC) a few days ago,I plan to use oracle so I edit pom.xml's properties:

```
<dbunit.schema>TEST</dbunit.schema>
<jdbc.driverClassName>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</jdbc.driverClassName>
<jdbc.groupId>com.oracle.driver</jdbc.groupId>
<jdbc.artifactId>jdbc-driver</jdbc.artifactId>
<jdbc.version>12</jdbc.version>
<jdbc.url>
  <![CDATA[jdbc:oracle:thin:@xx:1521:xx]]>
</jdbc.url>
<jdbc.username>xx</jdbc.username>
<jdbc.password>xx</jdbc.password>
```

when I run mvn -P oracle in cmd,I ran to this problem(the first part):

```html
[INFO] HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export drop table app_user cascade constraints; 
[ERROR] HHH000389: Unsuccessful: drop table app_user cascade constraints
[ERROR] ORA-00911: invalid character
.....
```

I googled and found out ora-00911 means "execute a SQL statement that included a special character." ,but I don't add anything in appfuse. Did I miss something?thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this problem,the default delimiter of the hibernate4-maven-plugin is ";" which cause ora-00911(not figure out when to use ;). so I add configuration in pom.xml's properties :

```html
<hibernate.export.schema.delimiter></hibernate.export.schema.delimiter>
```